# C# soap invokation are generating HEAD request and external server are blocking. How to remove these?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, http-head

I have a problem when I Invoke a soap action in a external server, when i monitoring my application,  wcf client generates me a lot of errors.
Is any way to don't this request (http HEAD)?

I'm using Basic authentication.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use credentials.  Roles are used : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true

Comment: You can refer to: https://eufuckingreka.wordpress.com/2019/01/02/web-service-call-getting-405-method-not-allowed/